linux: rebooting gracefully if possible, by force if required
I would like to setup on a raspberry pi a service that would:

attempt for one minute to reboot gracefully
but after one minute force reboot if some services fail to terminate

My (incorrect ?) understanding is that:

shutdown -r now : will exit gracefully but may hang it a service fails to stop
shutdown -r +1 : same, but in one minute (but may still hang)
systemctl reboot --force : will brutally reboot

None of the command above seems suitable for my need.

please [edit] your question to include the OS and distro you are trying to achieve this with
